# Simple Python script using loads of memory

Tags: python, memory, optimization, sympy

I'm writing a very simple script that reads a  fairly large file (3M lines, 1.1G file) that contains litteral (str) expression of polynomial. I then use Sympy for some symbolic calculation and write results to 16 separate files.

My script, as it runs, takes an increasing memory space (> 20 Gb), and I can't understand why. Would you see any way to improve the memory usage of that script ?

```
from sympy import sympify
from sympy.abc import x,y
from sympy import degree

fin = open("out_poly","r")
A = fin.readlines()
fin.close()
deg = 4
fou = [open("coeff_x"+str(i)+"y"+str(k),"w") for i in range(deg+1) for k in range(deg+1-i)]

for line in A:
  expr = line.replace("^","**").replace("x0","x").replace("x1","y")
  exprsy = sympify(expr)
  cpt = 0
  for i in range(deg+1):
    for k in range(deg+1-i):
      fou[cpt].write(str(exprsy.coeff(x,i).coeff(y,k))+"\n")
      cpt = cpt+1

for files in fou:
  files.close()
```

Comment: Try `for line in fin` instead of the setup with `readlines()` you have now. Seems there is no need to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: In addition, you should write, and then close each output file in turn, instead of only closing them when they are all filled. At the end of the program you have a bunch of big output files in memory, explaining the 20GB memory usage.

Comment: @Junuxx: Open files you're writing to shouldn't cause memory issues. Once you write enough data to a file for the internal buffering to flush, it should only remain in memory if the OS decides to keep it in a disk cache of some kind (which you can't control, nor should you need to). And given the way the output is generated (one line of output to each file for each line of input) there's really no practical way to do them one by one (unless you want to read the 3M lines 24 times, rather than once).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it! The culprit was... Sympy!

Sympy caches expressions and fills up the memory. The problem can be solved either by setting up the environment variable SYMPY_NO_CACHE=no, but it can seriously affect Sympy performance. A better alternative is to import the following Sympy extension:

```
from sympy.core.cache import *
```

and clear up the cache in your code at adequate intervals:

```
clear_cache()
```

With those commands at each iteration in my code, the memory usage is stable and constant at only 26 Mo.

Links about the issue: http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=3222

Links about Sympy cache: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/faq

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't realized that!

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue. SymPy really needs to implement LRU to keep the cache size down. Patches welcome!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably because `fin` is too large to be stored in the buffer. These lines:

```
fin = open("out_poly","r")
A = fin.readlines()
fin.close()
```

stores the whole content of `fin` in the memory, which is why you are taking so much space in the memory.

Instead of storing it in `A`, you can loop straight through the file itself:

```
from sympy import sympify
from sympy.abc import x,y
from sympy import degree

deg = 4
fou = [open("coeff_x"+str(i)+"y"+str(k),"w") for i in range(deg+1) for k in range(deg+1-i)]

with open("out_poly") as A:
    for line in A:
      expr = line.replace("^","**").replace("x0","x").replace("x1","y")
      exprsy = sympify(expr)
      cpt = 0
      for i in range(deg+1):
        for k in range(deg+1-i):
          fou[cpt].write(str(exprsy.coeff(x,i).coeff(y,k))+"\n")
          fou[cpt].close() #close it straight away, so we don't need to close it later
          cpt = cpt+1
```

With this, it reads the file itself per line, not a copy of the file that is stored in the memory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for you suggestion on the fin processing, unfortunately I already tried this syntax (albeit with a for lines in open(xx) because of python 2.4) and it produced the same problem. Also, I cannot close the fou[cpt] stream, because each line of fin produces a line in fou[cpt].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today! In my case cache wouldn't really bring any benefit as I knew that 
my code wouldn't benefit from cache (sympy was used inside fitted function, and on each iteration parameters would be different).

So I wanted to disable cache altogether, and it turns out that it is possible: there is a enviorment variable: `SYMPY_USE_CACHE`. If it is set to `yes` cache is enabled if it is set to `no` it is disabled altogether.

So I just added:

```
export SYMPY_USE_CACHE=no
```